# Not able to access the variable declared outside the function in UITableviewcontroller swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, variables, scope

I am using a simple UITableViewController

```
var testdata = [String]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("controlcell",
forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.clabel.text = testdata[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

testdata is declared outside the function. testdata is also populated from another method.

The issue is: self.testdata shows no data when I put a breakpoint and check the data.
Am I using the variable correctly in swift ?

Adding complete code here:

```
 import UIKit
 import Alamofire


 class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource,             UITableViewDelegate {

struct ListItem {
    var Name:String = ""
    var Number:String = ""
    var Email:String = ""
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getjsonData()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
   // return controlstaticdata.count
   // return controlListData.controlListItems.count
    return testdata.count
}

   var testdata = [String]()


    func getjsonData(){

     var jsondata:NSData!

    let url = "http://localhost:3000/controllistapp"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON(){
        (_,_,data,_) in
        println(data)

    // parse the jsondata returned by Alamofire .GET request

    let json = JSON(data!)
    var i = 0
    for(_, subJson): (String, JSON) in json {
        if let Name = subJson["Name"].string,
            let Number = subJson["Number"].string,
            let Email = subJson["Email"].string{
                var item = ListItem(Name: Name, Number: Number, Email: Email)
                self.testdata += [Name]

        }

    }
}

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("controlcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.clabel.text = self.testdata[indexPath.row]
    return cell
} 
}
```

A breakpoint at line self.testdata += [Name] in getjsonData shows the data being populated. 
However, a breakpoint at line cell.clabel.text = self.testdata[indexPath.row] in tableView function shows there is no data and throws an exception.

Comment: Please show how you populate testdata

Comment: I have updated the post with complete code.

Comment: Are you sure that something is written into the array in the for loop? Otherwise try to initialize the array as `var testdata:[String] = []`

Comment: I have tried var testdata:[String] = [] now . Same result.   I can see the testdata getting populated in debug window at breakpoint. However, when I break in TableView its empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you forgot to include self.tableView.reloadData() after you populate data into the array

Comment: I have added data to test data from another function in the same controller.  Still the same issue. If it is a static array then I can access the data. But for var array, the data is not available.

Comment: I think you forgot to reload the tableView After you put data into the array.. Check the edit answer